# Generics or not Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Basically I have a custom List class that contains different fruits. Assume that each fruit has an ID number that is stored in the list.

Is it better to have:

```
new AppleList();
new OrangeList();
new LemonList();
```

or

```
new FruitList<Fruit.Apple>();
new FruitList<Fruit.Orange>();
new FruitList<Fruit.Lemon>();
```

Things to consider:

- All IDs are of type int.
- The type of the fruit will not affect the implementation of the List itself. It will only be used by the client of the list, like an external method, etc.

I would like to use the one that is clearer, better in design, faster, more efficient, etc. Additionally if these above 2 techniques are not the best, please suggest your ideas.

EDIT: Btw Fruit is an enum if that wasn't clear.

Comment: you're doing a list of enums?? that's not really what lists are for. enums are a sort of list already.

Comment: Thanks, no not a list of enums. It's just there for type. ALl these lists will store ints, like 1,2,3,4.

Comment: I am really surprised how many people didn't understand that you are storing a list of integers.

Comment: I think part of the problem is the overly abstract nature of your question.  Perhaps you should pose it in real word terms?

Comment: @Mystere Man: I don't think I can write this question any simpler. The actually usage is very complex and includes so many "redundant" info, that would take a lot of time to level up. But in effect, this question captures the essence of the problem.

Comment: I don't think it does, I think the nature of the way you phrased it is causing confusion.  This is the same reason so many people have trouble learning OOP in the first place, because people insist on stupid analogies like "Fruit" or "Animals".

Comment: I should clarify, I'm not calling your question stupid, just the analogies ;)

Comment: lol, partly true, but like I said I just wanted to get the focus of the question where it matters. In the real case, the extra details would remove the focus from the main question.

Comment: Trying to learn about generics most confusing post ever. Should have been more descriptive, it should never had ranked so high on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> •All IDs are of type int.
>
> •The type of the fruit will not affect the implementation of the List itself. It will only be used by the client of the list, like an external method, etc.

Given these two facts, I wouldn't bother with generics. I would put a normal property on FruitList to indicate which type of fruit it is.

Comment: Why should he maintain 3 different lists doing the same. The only difference here is the contained ids for different type of fruit but it does not affect the list behaviour. Why not just use var appleList = new List<int>()...

Answer (score 10):

Use a combo:

```
public class AppleList : FruitList<Apple> { ... }
public class OrangeList : FruitList<Orange> { ... }
public class LemonList : FruitList<Lemon> { ... }
```

Put the common logic in the base list class:

```
public class FruitList<T> : List<T>
    where T : IFruit 
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, this wouldn't work I think. Because all fruit lists will be 100% the same. But I still need a way to distinguish them externally.

Comment: If they're all the same, then you can just have AppleList : List<Apple>

Comment: Thanks. Is Apple a class in your case? Also why inherit from List? Just wondering.

Comment: Because you get all the functionality of list that you can build on top of

Answer (score 9):

If you use generics, is there a purpose to create the FruitList type? Could you just use List?

There won't be much difference in performance, so I say why create three different classes when one would do the same exactly thing? Use the generic solution.

Comment: Thanks, yeah FruitList is necessary to implement new interfaces and also have some functionality in there that List doesn't.

Comment: Like what?  Couldn't your functionality be served with Extension methods on a normal list?  What do you mean by "necessary to implement new interfaces"?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Extension methods in a class that have control of.

Comment: @gcores: you won't recommend ext methods on a class that we have no control? Just wondering.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Mystere Man: Ok so my List is quite different, like I have different interfaces that are relied from other classes which List doesn't implement.

Comment: Exactly, extension methods are *designed* for classes you have no control over, that's their purpose.

Comment: if you control the class, just write real methods. if the methods are shared across classes, write a base class/interface

Comment: Joan, can you give an example?

Comment: I'm just saying that it's better to use inheritance if you can, there's nothing wrong with subclassing List<> and add whatever method you need.

Comment: Be careful though, inheritance and polymorphism is a good thing, but if overdone, it can create a giant tangle of coupling that will make your code harder to modify in the future (which is ironic, because if done well, it has the opposite affect).

Comment: @Mystere Man: Ok say a property like IsCached in ICacheable. Whoever is using this list has to know if it's cached or not.

Comment: I prefer not to inherit unless I have to, or if it makes more sense to inherit.  Extension methods are a perfectly viable way to give things more functionality.  After all, that's how LINQ is implemented.

Comment: @Mystere Man: I agree on the ext methods. Another reason why I go with my own types is because, i need total control on the code and I have so many first class types that are used in my app but these types have to conform with so many guidelines that are defined in the app itself.

Comment: The problem with extension methods (currently) is that they may not be supported in all languages.  Avoid them if you have to ship your code off to areas you can't control.  Also, it may not be obvious to developers what namespace to use in order to get the benefit of your ext methods.

Comment: That's my only gripe with extension methods... they aren't very "discoverable"

Comment: @Michael, which language do you use that doesn't support extension methods?

Answer (score 7):

It's much easier to maintain 1 generic list than 3 non-generic versions.  If you really like the AppleList name you can always use the using trick to name a generic list

```
using AppleList=Fruit.FruitList<Fruit.Apple>
```

Comment: If he really needs AppleList, then using a "trick" to make it look like AppleList doesn't actually make it an AppleList.

Comment: I didn't know this syntax used thsi way. SO when I say AppleList, it will create FruitList<Fruit.Apple>?

Comment: @Max, I think you're misunderstanding the question.  The OP is asking if they should create 3 list types or just one generic one.  My solution is allowing for a "friendly" name for a generic list.  They should in principle have all the same methods.

Answer (score 3):

Reuse the generic collection classes and subclass them only if you're adding additional functionality.  Keep your subclass implementation generic if you can.  This is the least complex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Generic list, no point in crating 3 lists and it's always good to keep a level of abstraction. (IFruit would be a good interface).

Comment: IFruit is good for what? It wouldn't apply to the INTEGERS being stored in the list.

Comment: Why not just use var appleList = new List<int>(); The containment could be defined externally you could just create a class FruitList : List<int> { Fruit Type { get; }}

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend the accepted answer and I think you meant something like this instead:

```
public enum Fruit
{
   Apple,
   Orange,
   Lemon
}

public interface IFruitList : IList<int>
{
   Fruit Type { get; }
};

public class FruitList : List<int>, IFruitList
{
   private readonly type;

   FruitList(Fruit type)
     : base()
   {
      this.type = type;
   }

   FruitList(Fruit type, IEnumerable<int> collection)
     : base(collection)
   {
      this.type = type;
   }

   Fruit Type { return type; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assume [YAGNI](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) unless you need it.  Therefore, if you don't need antyhing more than you get in List, then just `List<T>`.  If for some reason you have to override List, then create

```
FruitList<T> : List<T> where T : Fruit
```

If your lists diverge and are no longer polymorphic, then consider implementing your custom lists:

- `AppleList`
- `OrangeList`
- `LemonList`

Try as best you can, however, to keep your inheritance hierarchy as flat as possible to avoid overcomplicating your solution.

Comment: You were not listening. The list contains integers, not Fruits.

Comment: Actually I don't know this: is List not a sealed class?

Comment: List<T> is definitely not sealed.

Comment: @Grauenwolf Joan stated that the ID is an int. If fruit was an int, then it would be impossible to do this: new FruitList<Fruit.Apple>(); which is included in the example. Apple must be a nested type of Fruit... but thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: No, the List contains Fruit. Maybe only FruitList : List<T> would be enough, and FruitList<T> not necessary, but the answer is still correct.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't actually used inheritance on fruits because I used enum. Is this not the better way in this case? I figured if the type of fruit is only important for other methods, why create new classes?